# TALEND Studio v8 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/talend/fileprocess/FileInputDelimited

Tags: java-11, talend

I am migrating a Talend 6 project to Talend 8. We have redone the install, defined jdk11 in the Talend Studio properties, tested the project in Talend Studio and everything works as intended. When building the job, exporting and installing it, as it is called by our Java/Python app directly on the server, I get this error:

`Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/talend/fileprocess/FileInputDelimited`

I have checked and it has its lib correctly exported, including the talend_file_enhanced_1.1 jar, that normally includes this component.

Does anyone have any idea of what exactly I am missing here ? Thank you.